# Make a webm blob into a file to upload to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob, webm

i'm developing a chat software with audio recording.

I want to upload the webm file to cloudinary, Which would work if u could turn it into a file.

This code turns the recorded data into a webm file and downloads it to my computer. this was made to test if the recording actually works.

Now i need to turn this into a file and upload it.

I dont know how to exactly turn it into a file which i do not download immediately

```
 function handleStop(recordedBlob) {
   console.log('recordedBlob is: ', recordedBlob);
   const fileName = chatId + '-' + Date.now() + '-' + author;

   const a = document.createElement('a');
   a.download = `${fileName}.webm`;
   a.href = recordedBlob.blobURL;
   a.click();

   setNewAudioFile(//SHOULD BE A WEBM FILE);
 }
```

Comment: you'd `POST` recordedBlob to the server using fetch or XMLHttpRequest

Comment: so i can just skip the conversion to webm because it already is a webm?

Comment: which part of the code you posted do you believe is *converting* anything?

Comment: i guess with the download and href part I'm turning it into an actual file?!

Comment: no, when your computer saves it on your hard drive, that's when it *becomes an actual file* - before that, it's a bunch of 1's an 0's ... which you could just as easily `POST` to the server using fetch or XMLHttpRequest

Comment: AAahh, i understand. Thanks a lot for clarifying. 
Is there any way to run this in JS? The file-naming is crucial and the webm is saved to cloudinary.

Comment: the file naming is **up to your server** as that is where the *file* is created

Comment: thanks for your help! I understand more about what i'm trying to do now :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
data = new FormData();
data.append('file', recordedBlob);

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/uploadaudio",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {


        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("failure");
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `async:false`? never ... never ever ... especially on a LARGE upload ... should you `async: false` - also, jQuery is **never the answer**

Comment: I have edited my code and removed async. I hope this is useful for the person who have asked this. Can you please upvote my anser if it works :-) Hala, Happy coding :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. My post request is going to cloudinary. This request is working fine.  I'm just struggling with the file itself because cloudinary just does not want to let me upload a blob